# Code coverage for scheduler class

Tags: apex, schedulebatch

I have a scheduler class that looks like this

```
global class PBEntryUpdateScheduler implements Schedulable {

    public static String executionTime = '0 0 3 * * ?';


    global static String scheduleMe() {
        PBEntryUpdateScheduler ScheduleClass = new PBEntryUpdateScheduler(); 
        return System.schedule('Batch execution', executionTime, ScheduleClass);
    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {

        PBEntryUpdateBatch b1 = new PBEntryUpdateBatch();
        Database.executebatch(b1);

    }
}
```

But so far my test coverage is only 57%. 
My test class looks like this:

```
@isTest
private class PBEntryUpdateSchedulerTest {


    @isTest static void testScheduleMe() {

        Test.startTest();

        PBEntryUpdateScheduler bpEntry = new PBEntryUpdateScheduler();
        String newExeTime = '0 0 3 * * ?';
        String jobId = System.schedule('Scheduler Test', newExeTime, bpEntry);

        Test.stopTest();


    }


}
```

Can anyone help in getting the code coverage to 75%?

Comment: note using Keith's answer, you should also assert that an asyncApexJob was created as otherwise you're not proving that a schedulable was started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launching via the static method - presumably added to make that simple - should help:

```
@isTest static void testScheduleMe() {

    // Set up any data needed for the code to work

    Test.startTest();
    PBEntryUpdateScheduler.scheduleMe();
    Test.stopTest();

    // Assert that the results you expect are present
}
```

Comment: that helped! thanks a lot Keith C.